# How to send data from BASH array to SQL array

Tags: sql, arrays, bash

I need to send data from the `bash` array to the `SQL` array AS IS.
What I mean:

**BASH** array

```
Arr=("\"'A'\", \"'B'\"")
echo ${Arr[@]}
"'A'", "'B'"
```

BUT! When I run this script like this `bash -x myscript.sh` I received this info into output:

```
bash -x myscript.sh
...
 + echo '"'\''A'\''",' '"'\''B'\''"'
 "'A'", "'B'"
```

Then I try to put data from the array `${Arr[@]}` into `SQL` select:

```
SELECT ip FROM some_table WHERE ip in ('${Arr[@]}')
```

As a result of this action into `SQL` array will be put this info `'"'\''A'\''",' '"'\''B'\''"'` and when I'll try to run this select I'll receive this error:

`ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name '"'B'")`

`Remarks`
If I do select manually `SELECT ip FROM some_table WHERE ip in ("'A'", "'B'")` everything works perfectly.

What I missed?
Thanks.

Comment: Not reproducible. `echo ${Arr[@]}` prints `'A', 'B'` here.

Comment: Sorry, missed some characters.

Comment: How did you use SELECT in bash script ? Can you paste more info ?

Comment: Here is a very short variant:
```Arr=("\"'A'\", \"'B'\"");
mysql --host=127.0.01 --user="user" --password="password" --database="databese" -e 'SELECT ip FROM some_table WHERE ip in ('${Arr[@]}')'```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arr=(\"\'A\'\",\"\'B\'\") 

echo "SELECT ip FROM some_table WHERE ip in (${Arr[@]})"

SELECT ip FROM some_table WHERE ip in ("'A'","'B'")
```

Comment: Unfortunately no... In this case, I received this error/info:

```Mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```